# In BigQuery, how to query a table using fully qualified name where project name contains - hyphen

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to run this cmd, and it seems BigQuery doesn't like the - in project name. **And com-fin-dev is not my default project**.

```
bq --location=US query --use_legacy_sql=false "SELECT col FROM com-fin-dev:my_schema.my_table LIMIT 10"
```

```
Syntax error: Unexpected "-"
```

Any alternative ways i can use the fully qualified table name, in BigQuery where project name contains - hyphen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the shell that I use, I have to escape the backticks:

```
bq --location=US query --use_legacy_sql=false \
    "SELECT col FROM \`com-fin-dev.my_schema.my_table\` LIMIT 10"
```

Note that you only need to escape the project name:

```
bq --location=US query --use_legacy_sql=false \
    "SELECT col FROM \`com-fin-dev\`.my_schema.my_table LIMIT 10"
```

Answer (score 1):

you should use below "spelling"

```
`com-fin-dev.my_schema.my_table`
```

Comment: Nope, still giving the same error. I tried that option already.

Comment: obviously you need to escape it(ticks) then! :o) also note the use of `.` versus `:` after project name